# Creating a SearchView that looks like the material design guidelines

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat, searchview, material-design

I'm currently in the process of learning how to convert my app to Material design and I'm a bit stuck right now. I've got the Toolbar added and I have made my navigation drawer overlay all the content.
I'm now trying to create an expandable search that looks like the one in the [material guidelines](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search):
[image]
This is what I've got right now and I can't figure out how to make it like the above:
[image: My search]

This is my menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

That works, I get a menu item that expands to the SearchView and I can filter my list fine. It doesn't look anything like the 1st picture though.
I tried to use `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()` on `R.id.action_search` so I could change the home icon to a back arrow, but that doesn't seem to work. Nothing gets fired in the listener. Even if that worked it still wouldn't be very close to the 1st image.
How do I create a SearchView in the new appcompat toolbar that looks like the material guidelines?

Comment: app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41013994/5326551

Answer (score 84, accepted):

After a week of puzzling over this. I think I've figured it out.
I'm now using just an EditText inside of the Toolbar. This was suggested to me by oj88 on reddit.

I now have this:
[image: New SearchView]
First inside onCreate() of my activity I added the EditText with an image view on the right hand side to the Toolbar like this:

```
    // Setup search container view
    searchContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams containerParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    containerParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    searchContainer.setLayoutParams(containerParams);

    // Setup search view
    toolbarSearchView = new EditText(this);
    // Set width / height / gravity
    int[] textSizeAttr = new int[]{android.R.attr.actionBarSize};
    int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(new TypedValue().data, textSizeAttr);
    int actionBarHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
    a.recycle();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, actionBarHeight);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    params.weight = 1;
    toolbarSearchView.setLayoutParams(params);

    // Setup display
    toolbarSearchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    toolbarSearchView.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);
    toolbarSearchView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbarSearchView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    toolbarSearchView.setSingleLine(true);
    toolbarSearchView.setImeActionLabel("Search", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED);
    toolbarSearchView.setHint("Search");
    toolbarSearchView.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b3ffffff"));
    try {
        // Set cursor colour to white
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544231/1692770
        // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564
        Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(toolbarSearchView, R.drawable.edittext_whitecursor);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    // Search text changed listener
    toolbarSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Fragment mainFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if (mainFragment != null && mainFragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
                ((MainListFragment) mainFragment).search(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438918/1692770
            if (s.toString().length() <= 0) {
                toolbarSearchView.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b3ffffff"));
            }
        }
    });
    ((LinearLayout) searchContainer).addView(toolbarSearchView);

    // Setup the clear button
    searchClearButton = new ImageView(this);
    Resources r = getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams clearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    clearParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    searchClearButton.setLayoutParams(clearParams);
    searchClearButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp); // TODO: Get this image from here: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons
    searchClearButton.setPadding(px, 0, px, 0);
    searchClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbarSearchView.setText("");
        }
    });
    ((LinearLayout) searchContainer).addView(searchClearButton);

    // Add search view to toolbar and hide it
    searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbar.addView(searchContainer);
```

This worked, but then I came across an issue where onOptionsItemSelected() wasn't being called when I tapped on the home button. So I wasn't able to cancel the search by pressing the home button. I tried a few different ways of registering the click listener on the home button but they didn't work. 
Eventually I found out that the ActionBarDrawerToggle I had was interfering with things, so I removed it. This listener then started working:

```
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // toolbarHomeButtonAnimating is a boolean that is initialized as false. It's used to stop the user pressing the home button while it is animating and breaking things.
            if (!toolbarHomeButtonAnimating) {
                // Here you'll want to check if you have a search query set, if you don't then hide the search box.
                // My main fragment handles this stuff, so I call its methods.
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                final Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
                    if (((MainListFragment) fragment).hasSearchQuery() || searchContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        displaySearchView(false);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer)))
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer));
            else
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer));
        }
    });
```

So I can now cancel the search with the home button, but I can't press the back button to cancel it yet. So I added this to onBackPressed():

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment mainFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (mainFragment != null && mainFragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
        if (((MainListFragment) mainFragment).hasSearchQuery() || searchContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            displaySearchView(false);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I created this method to toggle visibility of the EditText and menu item:

```
public void displaySearchView(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        // Stops user from being able to open drawer while searching
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

        // Hide search button, display EditText
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        searchContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Animate the home icon to the back arrow
        toggleActionBarIcon(ActionDrawableState.ARROW, mDrawerToggle, true);

        // Shift focus to the search EditText
        toolbarSearchView.requestFocus();

        // Pop up the soft keyboard
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                toolbarSearchView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
                toolbarSearchView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }, 200);
    } else {
        // Allows user to open drawer again
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

        // Hide the EditText and put the search button back on the Toolbar.
        // This sometimes fails when it isn't postDelayed(), don't know why.
        toolbarSearchView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toolbarSearchView.setText("");
                searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
            }
        }, 200);

        // Turn the home button back into a drawer icon
        toggleActionBarIcon(ActionDrawableState.BURGER, mDrawerToggle, true);

        // Hide the keyboard because the search box has been hidden
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(toolbarSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

I needed a way to toggle the home button on the toolbar between the drawer icon and the back button. I eventually found the method below in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836272/1692770). Though I modified it slightly to made more sense to me:

```
private enum ActionDrawableState {
    BURGER, ARROW
}

/**
 * Modified version of this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836272/1692770<br>
 * I flipped the start offset around for the animations because it seemed like it was the wrong way around to me.<br>
 * I also added a listener to the animation so I can find out when the home button has finished rotating.
 */
private void toggleActionBarIcon(final ActionDrawableState state, final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle, boolean animate) {
    if (animate) {
        float start = state == ActionDrawableState.BURGER ? 1.0f : 0f;
        float end = Math.abs(start - 1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ValueAnimator offsetAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start, end);
            offsetAnimator.setDuration(300);
            offsetAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            offsetAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float offset = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    toggle.onDrawerSlide(null, offset);
                }
            });
            offsetAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    toolbarHomeButtonAnimating = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
            toolbarHomeButtonAnimating = true;
            offsetAnimator.start();
        }
    } else {
        if (state == ActionDrawableState.BURGER) {
            toggle.onDrawerClosed(null);
        } else {
            toggle.onDrawerOpened(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This works, I've managed to work out a few bugs that I found along the way. I don't think it's 100% but it works well enough for me.

EDIT: If you want to add the search view in XML instead of Java do this:

toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    contentInsetLeft="72dp"
    contentInsetStart="72dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="72dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#b3ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

onCreate() of your Activity:

```
    searchContainer = findViewById(R.id.search_container);
    toolbarSearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchClearButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_clear);

    // Setup search container view
    try {
        // Set cursor colour to white
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544231/1692770
        // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564
        Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(toolbarSearchView, R.drawable.edittext_whitecursor);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    // Search text changed listener
    toolbarSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Fragment mainFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if (mainFragment != null && mainFragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
                ((MainListFragment) mainFragment).search(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    // Clear search text when clear button is tapped
    searchClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbarSearchView.setText("");
        }
    });

    // Hide the search view
    searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Works great, looks great, thank you! However, instead of creating the layouts in code, I created the LinearLayout with the EditText and the ImageView in xml and just inflated it in onCreate.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do it in XML but I thought I was doing something wrong as Android Studio wouldn't give me autocomplete in the layout XML.

Comment: Can you please update this answer with respective XML layout design required for this? that can help other very well.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the XML layout for this, I've also added the code needed in onCreate for it to work. The rest should stay the same.

Comment: @Mike Can you please update your answer and put your complete github source code?

Comment: please post the complete project in github

Answer (score 153):

It is actually quite easy to do this, if you are using `android.support.v7` library.

### Step - 1

Declare a menu item

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

### Step - 2

Extend `AppCompatActivity` and in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` setup the SearchView.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

...

public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

    ... 

}
```

### Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had upvoted it, but which emulator are you using? I have tried it but I am not getting the `navigate-back` button, but rather a search icon, and its distance from the left edge of the screen is not the same as that between the `X` icon and the right edge of the screen (I don't have action overflow). [Posted the question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994512/how-to-make-the-distance-between-left-edge-of-toolbar-and-search-icon-same-as-th), can you look into it?

Comment: I use a real device running API-18. But works fine on Emulators API-15 and  API-22 so far.

Comment: its not a material search. it is only the usual old search in action bar

Comment: Nice, but how do make the search bar always visible without needing to click the Search icon?

Comment: I answered my own sub-question, to make it always visible without the need to click on the search button add the line `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);` to the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

Comment: another useful tidbit - if you want the search view to be expanded initially make sure you have `app:showAsAction="always"` and NOT `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`

Comment: How can I set the background to white when its searching?

Comment: @summers The toolbar is just a normal view. You may set the background color using `myToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`

Comment: As in; where should I be calling it? searchView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() ; doesnt get called

Comment: Also, using this method, even when the searchBar is expanded the OverflowIcon is still visible (ie, the 3-dots). But some apps, handle search, by expanding it completely and changing the background to white. Like GMail

Comment: Damn Google has a full documentation but nowhere did they mention the `app:actionViewClass` attribute to be mentioned in the `Menu.xml`. So bad! Thanks for the Answer, that worked!

Comment: @SubinSebastian how I can add an addTextChangedListener on this searchview ?

Comment: Hey guys I got my solution, you can use `setOnQueryTextListener` and give definition to it's override methods i.e. `onQueryTextChange` and `onQueryTextSubmit`.

Comment: Great answer but MenuItemCompat.getActionView(...) is deprecated.  Try using  
MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
   instead

Comment: I'm writing a Single Activity app, do this in the fragment, and the Hamburger button doesn't change to Back button. Anyone has a solution to that?

Answer (score 23):

I know its a old thread but still posting the library I just made. Hope this might help someone.

https://github.com/Shahroz16/material-searchview

[image: Meterial Search View]

Comment: It's not hard, but I like your work. It saves my time to create my own searchview. Thanks, bro!

Answer (score 21):

The first screenshot in your question is not a public widget. The support SearchView ([`android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java)) mimics Android 5.0 Lollipop's SearchView ([`android.widget.SearchView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java)). Your second screenshot is used by other material designed apps like Google Play.

The SearchView in your first screenshot is used in Drive, YouTube and other closed source Google Apps. Fortunately, it is also used in the [Android 5.0 Dialer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/lollipop-release/src/com/android/dialer/). You can try to backport the view, but it uses some 5.0 APIs.

The classes which you will want to look at are:

[SearchEditTextLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/lollipop-release/src/com/android/dialer/widget/SearchEditTextLayout.java), [AnimUtils](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PhoneCommon/+/lollipop-release/src/com/android/phone/common/animation/AnimUtils.java), and [DialtactsActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/lollipop-release/src/com/android/dialer/DialtactsActivity.java) to understand how to use the View. You will also need resources from [ContactsCommon](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/lollipop-release/res/).

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that, I was hoping there was something already out there that could do it. For now I've just used an EditText with a transparent background and it seems ok for what I need.

Comment: This answer is very disturbing to me. Why does google use a private widget that happens to match their own material design guideline and then publish a crappy widget for us that does not? And every developer is now out there struggling with this on his own? What possible reasoning for this?

Answer (score 18):

Here's  my attempt at doing this:

#### Step 1: Create a style named `SearchViewStyle`

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon -->
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/search</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the "underline" in the text -->
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <!-- Gets rid of the search icon when the SearchView is expanded -->
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <!-- The hint text that appears when the user has not typed anything -->
    <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
</style>
```

#### Step 2: Create a layout named `simple_search_view_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

#### Step 3: Create a menu item for this search view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        app:actionLayout="@layout/simple_search_view_item"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

#### Step 4: Inflate the menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_searchable_activity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

The only thing I wasn't able to do was to make it fill the entire width of the `Toolbar`. If someone could help me do that then that'd be golden.

Comment: `I wasn't able to do was to make it fill the entire width`, which support library version are you using? Try setting `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` for your Toolbar.

Comment: @LittleChild, try solution given by Magnesh. If still it is not get resolved then try to add below lines in toolbar. app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"

Comment: Thank you for putting explanation for each line in SearchViewStyle!

Comment: [Little Child](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1894684/little-child)
For entire width, you can do sth like this: 
("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946569/searchview-suggestion-layout-width-match-parent/45424885#45424885")

Answer (score 11):

To achieve desired look of SearchView, you can use styles.

First, you need to create `style` for your SearchView, which should look something like this:

```
<style name="CustomSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Whole list of attributes you can find at [this](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) article, under the "SearchView" section.

Secondly, you need to create a `style` for your `Toolbar`, which is used as ActionBar:

```
<style name="ToolbarSearchView" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchView</item>
</style>
```

And finally you need to update your Toolbar theme attribute this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarSearchView" />
```

Result:

[image]

NOTE: You need to change your `Toolbar` theme attribute directly. If you'll just update your main theme `searchViewStyle` attribute it wouldn't affect your `Toolbar`.

Comment: Hey did you add those `navigate-back` (back arrow) and `cancel` (the x) icons yourself or they were automatically added?

Comment: @Solace they are added automatically

Comment: Do they appear only when you start writing te search query in the SearchView or are they there even when you have not written anything and the search hint is visible? I am asking because mine do not appear until I start writing the query. So this information will be very useful for me

Comment: @Solace `navigate-back` is always shown, `clear` is shown only after you written some search query.

Answer (score 6):

Another way you can achieve the desired effect is to use this [Material Search View library](https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView). It handles search history automatically and it's possible to provide search suggestions to the view as well.

**Sample:** (It's shown in Portuguese, but it also works in english and italian).

[image: Sample]

### Setup

Before you can use this lib, you have to implement a class named `MsvAuthority` inside the `br.com.mauker` package on your app module, and it should have a public static String variable called `CONTENT_AUTHORITY`. Give it the value you want and **don't forget** to add the same name on your manifest file. The lib will use this file to set the Content Provider authority.

**Example:**

**MsvAuthority.java**

```
package br.com.mauker;

public class MsvAuthority {
    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.searchhistorydatabase";
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>

    <application ... >
        <provider
        android:name="br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.db.HistoryProvider"
        android:authorities="br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.searchhistorydatabase"
        android:exported="false"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:syncable="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### Usage

To use it, add the dependency:

```
compile 'br.com.mauker.materialsearchview:materialsearchview:1.2.0'
```

And then, on your `Activity` layout file, add the following:

```
<br.com.mauker.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

After that, you'll just need to get the `MaterialSearchView` reference by using `getViewById()`, and open it up or close it using `MaterialSearchView#openSearch()` and `MaterialSearchView#closeSearch()`.

**P.S.:** It's possible to open and close the view not only from the `Toolbar`. You can use the `openSearch()` method from basically any `Button`, such as a Floating Action Button.

```
// Inside onCreate()
MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchView.openSearch();
        }
    });
```

You can also close the view using the back button, doing the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (searchView.isOpen()) {
        // Close the search on the back button press.
        searchView.closeSearch();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

For more information on how to use the lib, [check the github page](https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView).

Comment: Excellent library, and great idea to abstract the open/close method so that a MenuItem isn't required to open/close it, I plan on using this in my app with a FloatingActionButton with a search icon, so it will work great.

Comment: Why aren't there parameters for strings like 'Search'? It seems the library limits people to either english or portuguese versions of the string :/

Comment: But it's possible to change the hint String by using styles as it's stated on the README. As for the voice input hint, it'll be released later: https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView/issues/23

Comment: @rpgmaker Check the latest update, it's now possible to change those strings.

Comment: @Mauker any idea how to set android:imeOptions="actionSearch" to the EditText of your component? (I want to display a "search" button in the keyboard)

Comment: @Mauker actually I've seen in your lib it is already there (android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi") but my keyboard doesn't display a loupe or a search specific button (only a enter button) Is that specific to the manufacturer or do I need to add something else?

Comment: What's your phone? @estoke (You can also open an issue on the github project so we can discuss this further)

Comment: Make sure to use the package br.com.mauker in `MsvAuthority`. I had changed it to my own project  package name and the app crashed when I was adding suggestions

Comment: You have to add your own authority, follow the README, you have to change it in two places to make it work, and avoid conflicts with other apps. There's will be an update where that won't be needed anymore, but there's no release date yet.

Answer (score 2):

The following will create a SearchView identical to the one in Gmail and add it to the given Toolbar.  You'll just have to implement your own "ViewUtil.convertDpToPixel" method.

```
private SearchView createMaterialSearchView(Toolbar toolbar, String hintText) {

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setMinimumHeight(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setQueryHint(hintText);

    int rightMarginFrame = 0;
    View frame = searchView.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_edit_frame", null, null));
    if (frame != null) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rightMarginFrame = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) frame.getLayoutParams()).rightMargin;
        frameParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        frame.setLayoutParams(frameParams);
    }

    View plate = searchView.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null));
    if (plate != null) {
        plate.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        plate.setPadding(0, 0, rightMarginFrame, 0);
        plate.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    int autoCompleteId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    if (searchView.findViewById(autoCompleteId) != null) {
        EditText autoComplete = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(autoCompleteId);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, (int) ViewUtil.convertDpToPixel(36));
        params.weight = 1;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        params.leftMargin = rightMarginFrame;
        autoComplete.setLayoutParams(params);
        autoComplete.setTextSize(16f);
    }

    int searchMagId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    if (searchView.findViewById(searchMagId) != null) {
        ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchMagId);
        v.setImageDrawable(null);
        v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    toolbar.setTitle(null);
    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
    toolbar.addView(searchView);

    return searchView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same Result by just adding the theme to the AppBarLayout. My theme code is: `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar"`

The complete code of my AppBarLayout is:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
         style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Surface"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar">

         <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
             app:menu="@menu/list_menu"
             app:title="@string/app_name"
             app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleStyle" />

     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**The Result:**

[image: Output:]