# SearchView Suggestion - Layout width: match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, searchview

How to display SearchView **suggestions** which use the whole screen width using `appcompat-v7:21`?

I use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView in code and the menu-resource. The new Toolbar widget has a `searchViewStyle`, but I couldn't find a parameter to display suggestions full width (match_parent).

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://d0od.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/material-makeover-4.jpeg))</sub>

Comment: create a nice lib, have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32693670/3722311

Answer (score 6):

you can do it like this:          (it's on DropDownAnchor)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    int searchEditTextId = R.id.search_src_text;
    final AutoCompleteTextView searchEditText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(searchEditTextId);
    final View dropDownAnchor = searchView.findViewById(searchEditText.getDropDownAnchor());

    if (dropDownAnchor != null) {
        dropDownAnchor.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

                // screen width
                int screenWidthPixel = ActivitySearchUni.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                searchEditText.setDropDownWidth(screenWidthPixel);
            }
        });
    }

    return true;
}
```