# SearchView like Google Play Video App

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, searchview

I'm trying to implement search interface in actionbar like in Google Play Video App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.videos).
I think it is SearchView widget but don't understand how do same customization: add up button inside it, set background, and expand the full width of actionbar

[image: Play Video screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style Android SearchView like in Google Play Store app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327504/how-to-style-android-searchview-like-in-google-play-store-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using not bad library for this: https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

Answer (score 3):

[@Quiny898](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088334/quinny898) create a nice lib, have a look:

https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

[image]

Comment: It's not been maintained for well over half a year and is formally discontinued. There are better alternatives now, such as https://github.com/lapism/SearchView and https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview

Answer (score 0):

Use a standalone Toolbar and set it with an elevation, then inflate your menu in it.

You can add this item to your menu:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    pawesome:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    pawesome:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```