# How to have a searchview, on the toolbar like google?

Tags: android, kotlin

I do not look for any function in the searchview, in the toolbar, the click is treated so that it is directed to a search activity.

Here is the toolbar I want:

[image]

This will always be expanded and clicking will be directed to another activity. Here are the codes:

XML ToolBar Home:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<!--                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    shapeColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onSearchClicked(view)}"
                    android:queryHint="Pesquisar"
                    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
                    android:voiceIcon="@drawable/ic_settings_voice_black_24px"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="false">
//TODO doesn't work
                </SearchView>-->

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Menu Home:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />
```

HomeActivity:

```
    override val contentView = R.layout.view_home

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean = when (item.itemId) {
/*        R.id.item_search -> {
            startActivity(Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java))
            true
        }*/
        R.id.item_zuk_code -> {
            givenPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, granted = {
                startActivity(Intent(this@HomeActivity, ZukCodeReaderActivity::class.java))
            })
            true
        }
//        R.id.item_contacts -> {
//            startActivity(Intent(this, ContactsSuggestionActivity::class.java))
//            true
//        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

**EDIT:**

HomeActivity Menu:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)

    val manager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search).actionView as android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    val si = manager.getSearchableInfo(componentName)

    var opt : Int = search.imeOptions
    search.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI
    search.backgroundTintMode
    search.setSearchableInfo(si)
    search.setIconifiedByDefault(false)

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

What I have:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529062/4409409  It's Java, not kotlin, but you can see how it uses a `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` instead of just opening an activity when the SearchView in the menu is selected, as you have it in your commented-out code.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you! But it did not give me the search bar I put as an example, just like the android contacts bar, or gmail.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327504/how-to-style-android-searchview-like-in-google-play-store-app

Comment: @DanielNugent I took a look but could not do it. Or I did not understand.This edittext does not appear for me