# Animating ListView sliding down

Tags: android, listview, animation, listadapter, animator

Trying to animate a search bar result, which is a listView contained in a FrameLayout. Basically, all it needs to do is when the search button is pressed, the listView drops down along with the ListItems populated by a listAdapter. Right now, I cannot find a way to animate this outside of the adapter's getView method. However, if I animate the adapter's getView method, this animation would animate every single time the listView changes, which is not desired in my case.

The list populates after nofityDataSetChanged is called, so how would I be able to know the size of the listView before it's fully populated? or what exactly is the right way of doing this.

I just need it to animate on the first time. Therefore, the question is is there a more elegant way of animating ListView without changing anything in the ListViewAdapters.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you just want to scroll down, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7032341/1394695

Comment: @anti_gone No, I want the frameLayout to dropdown like how Google Playstore does their search view. You click it, the search results drop down.

Comment: Duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775295/searchview-like-google-play-video-app