# How to implement Search Bar like gmail app in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, uisearchbar, material-design, android-search

I am trying to implement the **Search** functionality in my android app similar to latest gmail app (search icon in the action bar).

[image]

On tapping the Search icon, the action bar turns into a search field with a back button on the left side, and a microphone button on the right side. I want to have the same component in my app.

Is there any library or tutorial for this?

Is this possible to support this type of material design search in non-lollipop versions too. ?

Comment: You can with SearchView. Add a SearchView in some layout, add a layout in toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, also add android.support.v7 in your project), set toolbar as supportActionBar.

Comment: @n.m. : No i cant get this style in default search view and i want to support in all versions of android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This library to do this, the only thing it does not do is the ripples, but I expect you could implement them quite easily with other resources:

https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

Here the image of the work done in it.

[image]

Comment: the above library was deprecated...officially.

Answer (score 13):

i don´t know about the lollipop version, but if you want a search like that, you can add this "main_activity_actions" to your action bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

and override this in your java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
    ...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), is the part of the dictionary but is the same idea, see ya!

Answer (score 0):

There are two out of the box APIs provided by Google called Search Dialog and Search View. You can use one or another - or both - to implement the desired behaviour. It alreads gives you a lot of what you want. The following link has a tutorial for it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: your example is too vague. I followed that tutorial and did not resulted a gmail searchview form