# how to get the material search on android action bar?

Tags: android, material-design

And also when I click I want that it goes to some new fragment so I can set another tabs or another layout for it . All I want basically is when I click it shows back button and a blank white screen and not the current screen I am working at.

SO please help me with it as soon as possible. Thank you :)

I have a normal material design search but o want to modify it and make it more impressive

Comment: please someone help asap

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines

Answer (score 2):

**Gradle Dependencies for AppCompat-v7**

To use the appcompat-v7 support library, we should add the library in Gradle dependency.

**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'**

***Android Manifest for SearchView***

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyCompatTheme">

            <!-- to identify this activity as "searchable" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

***Android SearchView in Menu***

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

***Styling Search View in Android Action Bar***

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/winBackground</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>
        <item name="background">@color/background</item>
    </style>

    <color name="winBackground">#98cb4a</color>
    <color name="background">#f76d3c</color>
</resources>
```

**Add the following searchable.xml file in folder “res/xml”**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

**Search View Main Activity**

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

SearchResultsActivity.java, in this class look at the way onNewIntent(Intent) method is overriden and handled. This is where we will get the search input query and our search against the data bank.

**SearchResultsActivity.java**

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class SearchResultsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_results.xml** -- the layout for search results

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff3dc0ff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search_result" />

</RelativeLayout>
```