# animate burger icon to arrow when searchview is open

Tags: java, android

I have a search view in my menu items like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:title="Search"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

and a navigation drawer in the same activity.

I want to animate burger icon into arrow icon when search view is open and then animates to burger when closed. how can I do that?

I've searched in stackoverflow and other sites but they do this just with navigation drawer.

Comment: Try to view this link [searchView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines) .