# Incorrect SearchView ActionBar icon shown

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, searchview

I have just added a `SearchView` to my app, and everything is working great, however the icon is acting strangely.

This is how it is currently:

[image]

However obviously this is how I want it to look:

[image]

As you can see, I've managed to get it to appear properly by changing the last line of this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

To this:

```
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

However, the problem with this is that when I search, the item on the left does not change to a back button like it should:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines

Comment: Awesome! I had tried looking up an existing answer, but I didn't find anything. Thanks a lot!