# How to implement Searchview in the layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I am trying to implement a searchView in the layout file just like other Views rather than on toolbar. Before I was using AutoCompleteTextView but now I wanted to implement SearchView. If anyone knows please help.

[Click here for the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne0iH.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what problems do you have with it?

Comment: I don't know where to start. You can see in the pic, what I wanted to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are lot of examples you can find. The best solution provided here:

[Creating a SearchView that looks like the material design guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines)

Also there are libraries available,the easiest library to implement is

https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch