# Searching JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json, search

my goal is to have a search bar in my app, but it's not fully functional yet. The search bar is there, but it has no function.

I'm following [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Book-Search-Tutorial) tutorial, but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.jsonparser;

import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://pastebin.com/raw/nL15tpa3";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemList;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                searchItem.collapseActionView();
                MainActivity.this.setTitle(query);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }

        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetItems().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray items = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Data");

                    // looping through All Items
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                        String ModelCode = c.getString("ModelCode");
                        String ModelName = c.getString("ModelName");

                        // tmp hash map for single item
                        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        item.put("ModelCode", ModelCode);
                        item.put("ModelName", ModelName);

                        // adding item to item list
                        itemList.add(item);
                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, itemList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"ModelCode", "ModelName"}, new int[]{R.id.ModelCode,
                    R.id.ModelName});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    private class ModelClient {
    }
}
```

**Search.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".BookListActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jsonparser.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ModelName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ModelCode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Were do you stuck, what is your problem, what do you already did to try to fix it?

Comment: I can see that you are using traditional way to bind JSON objects. Why don't you use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or Jackson like libraries to bind your json string to object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Z8FRtLc.png This part, especially the API part since the URL in my code doesn't have an API, it's directly JSON

Comment: @Chintan Rathod can GSON do JSON search? How?

Comment: It is not related to your question but it will remove your boilorplate code of `for` loop. Check [this tutorial](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Create searchable configuration xml file inside `res/xml/searchable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

And also define this searchable configuration as `meta-data` in `Manifest.xml`
like this:

```
<activity ... >
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

</activity>
```

Create `SearchActivity` and define `IntentFilters` to it:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity" ... >
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</activity>
```

This particular Activity will handle your search event.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html).

Comment: In the case of the `SearchActivity` derived from a list `Adapter`, should I just copy and paste the `MainActivity` `Adapter` to the `SearchActivity`? The interface in this tutorial is not my problem, but how to present the result is what I'm not getting.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Material SearchView

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
}
```

Must be last for right layering display

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary" />

    <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

[image]