# Android SearchView theme like Gmail app

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I would like to implement the `SearchView` with same effect as in Gmail app.

What I'm looking for is, how to have Dark Theme `Toolbar` and Light Theme `SearchView`? I attached images for better understanding. 

Basically Gmail app have a dark `Toolbar` and when user clicks search icon, the light `SearchView` appears. How I can achieve this behaviour? Actually I'm looking for 1:1 same design solution just with different colors. There should be some native way how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

[image: Dark Theme Toolbar]
[image: Light Theme SearchView]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines

Answer (score 3):

To achieve something like gmail app look into below Library

> https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView
>
> OR
>
> https://github.com/Mauker1/MaterialSearchView

It will definitely resolve your purpose

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks! The `MaterialSearchView` looks good to me. But I was more looking for some more native solution that will work in long therm. But anyway I'm going to check their implementation and then decide if I'll use library or just part of it.

Comment: you can thank me by doing upvote i guess. anyways i recommend to use part of library