# How to implement WhatsApp like material design SearchView?

Tags: android, material-design, searchview, android-toolbar, whatsapp

WhatsApp has such Toolbar:
[image]

When 'Search' menu item clicked, from the top SearchView comes down which takes whole space of toolbar:
[image]

When I tried to implement SearchView, it looks like this:
[image]

I found some libraries to implement this:
[Android Material SearchView by Eugene Horan](https://github.com/EugeneHoran/Android-Material-SearchView)
and [MaterialSearchView by krishnakapil](https://github.com/krishnakapil/MaterialSeachView). But they are not like in WhatsApp.

This question may seem weird, I could not find the way how to do this. So my question is how to implement WhatsApp like material design SearchView which comes from the top?

Answer (score 6):

I have developed a well received library by the comunity.

Does exactly what are you looking for.

[image]
[image]

Give it a try and tell if if was usufull for you.

Here it is the Github repo for [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView).

Comment: can you give me any idea on how to implement it in fragments with tabbar and viewpager? @MiguelCatalan

Comment: Could you please add an animation while searchview closes ? Or let me know how to put that from my code

Comment: Sorry @BhargavThanki, this library is no longer maintained. Feel free to take a look at the code and if you could do a PR I will promise to take the time to review it and merge it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I misread the question.

This answer should solve your issue.

Answer taken from :- [Creating a SearchView that looks like the material design guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556623/creating-a-searchview-that-looks-like-the-material-design-guidelines)

After a week of puzzling over this. I think I've figured it out.
I'm now using just an EditText inside of the Toolbar. This was suggested to me by oj88 on reddit.

I now have this:
[image: New SearchView]
First inside onCreate() of my activity I added the EditText with an image view on the right hand side to the Toolbar like this:

```
    // Setup search container view
    searchContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams containerParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    containerParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    searchContainer.setLayoutParams(containerParams);

    // Setup search view
    toolbarSearchView = new EditText(this);
    // Set width / height / gravity
    int[] textSizeAttr = new int[]{android.R.attr.actionBarSize};
    int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
    TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(new TypedValue().data, textSizeAttr);
    int actionBarHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
    a.recycle();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, actionBarHeight);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    params.weight = 1;
    toolbarSearchView.setLayoutParams(params);

    // Setup display
    toolbarSearchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    toolbarSearchView.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);
    toolbarSearchView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    toolbarSearchView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    toolbarSearchView.setSingleLine(true);
    toolbarSearchView.setImeActionLabel("Search", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED);
    toolbarSearchView.setHint("Search");
    toolbarSearchView.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b3ffffff"));
    try {
        // Set cursor colour to white
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544231/1692770
        // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564
        Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(toolbarSearchView, R.drawable.edittext_whitecursor);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    // Search text changed listener
    toolbarSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Fragment mainFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if (mainFragment != null && mainFragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
                ((MainListFragment) mainFragment).search(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438918/1692770
            if (s.toString().length() <= 0) {
                toolbarSearchView.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#b3ffffff"));
            }
        }
    });
    ((LinearLayout) searchContainer).addView(toolbarSearchView);

    // Setup the clear button
    searchClearButton = new ImageView(this);
    Resources r = getResources();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams clearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    clearParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    searchClearButton.setLayoutParams(clearParams);
    searchClearButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp); // TODO: Get this image from here: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons
    searchClearButton.setPadding(px, 0, px, 0);
    searchClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbarSearchView.setText("");
        }
    });
    ((LinearLayout) searchContainer).addView(searchClearButton);

    // Add search view to toolbar and hide it
    searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbar.addView(searchContainer);
```

This worked, but then I came across an issue where onOptionsItemSelected() wasn't being called when I tapped on the home button. So I wasn't able to cancel the search by pressing the home button. I tried a few different ways of registering the click listener on the home button but they didn't work. 
Eventually I found out that the ActionBarDrawerToggle I had was interfering with things, so I removed it. This listener then started working:

```
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // toolbarHomeButtonAnimating is a boolean that is initialized as false. It's used to stop the user pressing the home button while it is animating and breaking things.
            if (!toolbarHomeButtonAnimating) {
                // Here you'll want to check if you have a search query set, if you don't then hide the search box.
                // My main fragment handles this stuff, so I call its methods.
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                final Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
                    if (((MainListFragment) fragment).hasSearchQuery() || searchContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        displaySearchView(false);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer)))
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer));
            else
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer));
        }
    });
```

So I can now cancel the search with the home button, but I can't press the back button to cancel it yet. So I added this to onBackPressed():

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment mainFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    if (mainFragment != null && mainFragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
        if (((MainListFragment) mainFragment).hasSearchQuery() || searchContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            displaySearchView(false);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I created this method to toggle visibility of the EditText and menu item:

```
public void displaySearchView(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        // Stops user from being able to open drawer while searching
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

        // Hide search button, display EditText
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        searchContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Animate the home icon to the back arrow
        toggleActionBarIcon(ActionDrawableState.ARROW, mDrawerToggle, true);

        // Shift focus to the search EditText
        toolbarSearchView.requestFocus();

        // Pop up the soft keyboard
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                toolbarSearchView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
                toolbarSearchView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }, 200);
    } else {
        // Allows user to open drawer again
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

        // Hide the EditText and put the search button back on the Toolbar.
        // This sometimes fails when it isn't postDelayed(), don't know why.
        toolbarSearchView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toolbarSearchView.setText("");
                searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
            }
        }, 200);

        // Turn the home button back into a drawer icon
        toggleActionBarIcon(ActionDrawableState.BURGER, mDrawerToggle, true);

        // Hide the keyboard because the search box has been hidden
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(toolbarSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

I needed a way to toggle the home button on the toolbar between the drawer icon and the back button. I eventually found the method below in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836272/1692770). Though I modified it slightly to made more sense to me:

```
private enum ActionDrawableState {
    BURGER, ARROW
}

/**
 * Modified version of this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836272/1692770<br>
 * I flipped the start offset around for the animations because it seemed like it was the wrong way around to me.<br>
 * I also added a listener to the animation so I can find out when the home button has finished rotating.
 */
private void toggleActionBarIcon(final ActionDrawableState state, final ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle, boolean animate) {
    if (animate) {
        float start = state == ActionDrawableState.BURGER ? 1.0f : 0f;
        float end = Math.abs(start - 1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ValueAnimator offsetAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start, end);
            offsetAnimator.setDuration(300);
            offsetAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            offsetAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    float offset = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    toggle.onDrawerSlide(null, offset);
                }
            });
            offsetAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    toolbarHomeButtonAnimating = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
            toolbarHomeButtonAnimating = true;
            offsetAnimator.start();
        }
    } else {
        if (state == ActionDrawableState.BURGER) {
            toggle.onDrawerClosed(null);
        } else {
            toggle.onDrawerOpened(null);
        }
    }
}
```

This works, I've managed to work out a few bugs that I found along the way. I don't think it's 100% but it works well enough for me.

EDIT: If you want to add the search view in XML instead of Java do this:

toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    contentInsetLeft="72dp"
    contentInsetStart="72dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="72dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#b3ffffff" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

onCreate() of your Activity:

```
    searchContainer = findViewById(R.id.search_container);
    toolbarSearchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchClearButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_clear);

    // Setup search container view
    try {
        // Set cursor colour to white
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26544231/1692770
        // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564
        Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(toolbarSearchView, R.drawable.edittext_whitecursor);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    // Search text changed listener
    toolbarSearchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Fragment mainFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            if (mainFragment != null && mainFragment instanceof MainListFragment) {
                ((MainListFragment) mainFragment).search(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    // Clear search text when clear button is tapped
    searchClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbarSearchView.setText("");
        }
    });

    // Hide the search view
    searchContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create this with `android.support.v7` library

First of all create menu item in menu.xml like:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Extend **AppCompatActivity** and retrieve the SearchView in **onCreateOptionsMenu** like:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

...

public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

    ... 

}
```

Thats it. Hope this helps you. Accept, if you find it useful.

Comment: This piece of code is still the implementation of the old SearchView. Why is it accepted as the answer?

Comment: i think this good approaching from the stretch. then people can extend it for more advance series.

Answer (score 2):

I've just post my open source which imitates exactly what whatsapp toolbar does (Include circular animation).
[image: Example]

[Code](https://github.com/UdiOshi85/libSearchToolbar)
[Full example](https://github.com/UdiOshi85/SearchToolbarExample)

Comment: is it compatible with viewpager?

Comment: @MohitYadav It's a View, put it where ever you want

Comment: one last question where should i initiate the lib (base activity or view pager's fragment) and how to implement it in kotlin.